# Why is Nokogiri returning gibberish when parsing response from XML API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm requesting data from an API and trying to parse with Nokogiri following the website (http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html).

But when I print the "parsed" data, it doesn't look like its parsed.

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1101368 name="jobtitle" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x11008b4 "Software Engineer – Austin, TX">]>,...
```

The data is there but its surrounded by this type of content:
`#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x11008b4...`

**My code:**

```
data = open("<api_url>")
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(data)
p @doc.xpath("//jobtitle")
```

What is happening here?
Does anyone have experience with Nokogiri and can advise on how to parse XML properly?

Note: This is being done in Rails.

Comment: p @doc.xpath("//jobtitle").to_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing out a Nokogiri object, not raw XML. Use `.content` to print out the nodes content, or `.to_xml` to print out XML from the parsed file.